# Vk api wall.post error #214: Wall post access is denied

Tags: vkontakte-api, javascript

Добрый день, товарищи.

Появилась проблема с публикацией поста на стену пользователя. Функция js  такая:

```
function post() {
    VK.api('wall.post', {
        owner_id:'{{ idVk }}', 
        message:'Переводы', 
        attachments:'photo-00000000_000000000,http://vk.com/app0000000'
    }, function(data) {
        if (!data.response) {
            alert('Error #' + data.error.error_code + ': ' + data.error.error_msg);
            if (data.error.error_code == '214') {
                alert('Необходимо разрешить приложению публикацию на Вашей стене.');
                VK.callMethod("showSettingsBox");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

А вызываю ее так:

```
<a href="#" onclick="post();">Разместить на стене</a>
```

В первом алеете выводится следующее:

> Error #214: Wall post access is denied

Причем в SettingsBox'е выделены все пункты. Не подскажите, в чем проблема?